# Kafka Admins timeout

Tags: java, apache-kafka, aws-msk

I have an AWS MSK cluster up and running. Connected to it and ran this command to create a test topic called `topicoteste`

```
usr/local/kafka_2.13-2.5.0/bin/kafka-topics --create --bootstrap-server BOOTSTRAP_STRING_HERE --partitions 1 --replication-factor 3 --topic topicoteste
```

These are the two errors I get. Any suggestions?

```
Error while executing topic command : org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Call(callName=listTopics, deadlineMs=1611587423888) timed out at 9223372036854775807 after 1 attempt(s)
[2021-01-25 15:09:24,312] ERROR Uncaught exception in thread 'kafka-admin-client-thread | adminclient-1': (org.apache.kafka.common.utils.KafkaThread)
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at java.base/java.nio.HeapByteBuffer.<init>(HeapByteBuffer.java:61)
    at java.base/java.nio.ByteBuffer.allocate(ByteBuffer.java:348)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.memory.MemoryPool$1.tryAllocate(MemoryPool.java:30)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.NetworkReceive.readFrom(NetworkReceive.java:113)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.KafkaChannel.receive(KafkaChannel.java:448)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.KafkaChannel.read(KafkaChannel.java:398)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.attemptRead(Selector.java:678)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.pollSelectionKeys(Selector.java:580)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.poll(Selector.java:485)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient.poll(NetworkClient.java:549)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.KafkaAdminClient$AdminClientRunnable.processRequests(KafkaAdminClient.java:1272)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.KafkaAdminClient$AdminClientRunnable.run(KafkaAdminClient.java:1203)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
[2021-01-25 15:09:24,314] ERROR java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Call(callName=listTopics, deadlineMs=1611587423888) timed out at 9223372036854775807 after 1 attempt(s)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.internals.KafkaFutureImpl.wrapAndThrow(KafkaFutureImpl.java:45)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.internals.KafkaFutureImpl.access$000(KafkaFutureImpl.java:32)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.internals.KafkaFutureImpl$SingleWaiter.await(KafkaFutureImpl.java:89)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.internals.KafkaFutureImpl.get(KafkaFutureImpl.java:260)
    at kafka.admin.TopicCommand$AdminClientTopicService.createTopic(TopicCommand.scala:227)
    at kafka.admin.TopicCommand$TopicService.createTopic(TopicCommand.scala:196)
    at kafka.admin.TopicCommand$TopicService.createTopic$(TopicCommand.scala:191)
    at kafka.admin.TopicCommand$AdminClientTopicService.createTopic(TopicCommand.scala:219)
    at kafka.admin.TopicCommand$.main(TopicCommand.scala:62)
    at kafka.admin.TopicCommand.main(TopicCommand.scala)
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Call(callName=listTopics, deadlineMs=1611587423888) timed out at 9223372036854775807 after 1 attempt(s)
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: The AdminClient thread has exited.
 (kafka.admin.TopicCommand$)
```

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem because the broker used TLS and the AdminClient was not configured to use TLS.

You can either run a PLAINTEXT-listener next to the TLS listener and use that to create topics or configure your admin client with `--command-config <ssl.conf>` and a file *ssl.conf* looking something like this:

```
ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm=https
security.protocol=SSL
ssl.keystore.location=/path/to/keystore.jks
ssl.keystore.password=password
ssl.key.password=password
ssl.truststore.location=/path/to/truststore.jks
ssl.truststore.password=password
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer, I created topic.properties and provided path to create topic and it is working fine :)